# how can i find topic-id in a group of Telegram

Tags: telegram, chat, alert, zabbix, zabbix-api

I want to find the topic-id of my Telegram Group. I have a group id but I don't know how can I find topic-id for each topic that I have in the group.

I was looking in Stackoverflow!but I was confused about the solution! Here is the solution in StackOverflow :
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74773675/how-to-get-topic-id-for-telegram-group-chat)
I want to send some messages by Zabbix for each problem!